# Remove elements from 2d Numpy array based on a list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements

Thank you in advance for taking a look at my post.

I have a 2d np.array called `actions` with shape (2,x) which contains `int`s

I have another 1d np.array `keys` with elements of the same type to the first dimension of `actions`:  `actions[0]`. I want to remove from `actions` all array elements which are in `keys`. I tried `diff = actions[:, not actions[0] == kids_keys]`but it returns a 3d array of (1,2,x) shape.

How can I get a (2,x) `diff` array back ?

For example:

```
actions = [[121122, 211122, 221122, ... 455544, 545544][0, 0.35, 0.75, ... 1, -0.25]]
keys = [211122 221122]
# The operation I am looking for:
actions - keys = [[121122, ... 455544, 545544][0, ... 1, -0.25]]
```

The error: The dimmentions of the diff array become (2,1,80) for some reason I dont know!
[image: The dimentions of the diff array become (2,1,80)]

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted code for this, so people can see where you are in the process of trying to solve it.  Sample input, and expected output would be helpful as well.

Comment: What's the shape of `not actions[0] == kids_keys`?

Comment: The duplicate is transposed, but you can either transpose your output or just operate on the right dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```py
mask = np.isin(actions[0], keys, invert=True)
result = actions[:, mask]
```

Comment: its seems to work great! I would like to ask what `~` means and if there is another way to do this operation faster.

Comment: @AlexanderIthakis The `~` was to invert the result of `np.isin` (so only those _not_ in `keys` are kept), but I changed it since, although inverting is a very fast operation, `np.isin` accepts an `invert` parameter to do the same more efficiently as part of the function call itself. About being faster, if I knew a better way to do it I'd post it :) `np.isin` is fairly fast, if all `keys` are always unique you can pass `assume_unique=True`. The masking is [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing), which is relatively expensive.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the detailed answered. Yes, my keys, are unique, I will definitely change it. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The following will filter out columns of `actions` that have a first row entry in the set `keys`:

```
import numpy as np
x = 10
actions = np.random.randint(5, size=(2,x))
print(actions)
keys = np.array([1,2,3])
print(keys)
filtered_actions = actions[:,~np.sum([actions[0,:] == key for key in keys], dtype=bool, axis=0)]
print(filtered_actions)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For some reason when I try your code in a terminal it works as intended, but when I use it in my code, I get the same problem I got with my approach. It returns, a ( 2, 1, x) dimention array instead of (2, x). Can you please help me.